# Write JSON with class and record types

Tags: json, delphi

```pascal
type
  tbet = record
    fteam1: string;
    fteam2: string;
    fskor: string
  end;
    
type
  tdeltio = class
  private
    fusername: string;
    fpassword: string;
    fbet: array of tbet;
    fprice: currency;
  end;
    
deltio := Tdeltio.Create;
deltio.fusername := 'Vanias';
deltio.fpassword := '12345';
deltio.fprice := '70';
SetLength(deltio.fbet, 1);
deltio.fbet[0].fteam1 := 'Team1';
deltio.fbet[0].fteam2 := 'Team2';
deltio.fbet[0].fskor := '1-1';
 
var json := Tjson.ObjectToJsonString(deltio);
```

`json` result is like that:

```json
{"username":"Vanias","password":"12345","bet":[["Team1","Team2","1-1"]],"price":70}
```

My problem is I expected something like this instead:

```json
{"username":"Vanias","password":"12345","bet":[{"Team1":"Team1","Team2":"Team2","skor":"1-1"}],"price":70}
```

Why does the record type not have the property names? Ι know I can use a class for the `tbet` type, but I prefer a record type.

Comment: `Record`s are not `class`es. Make your `tbet` type a class, too, so it also becomes an object instead of an array for JSON.

Comment: Yes  i need to keep it as type record as said above. If there is no solution i will change it to class.

Comment: as already told you  record needs to be a class but this way is also terrible wrong you need to learn to create json objects and arrays with Tjsonobject.create and tjsonarray..create and all your problems will gone.

Answer (score 4):

`TJson` is *hard-coded* to marshal a `record` type as a JSON array, not as a JSON object. This is by design, and you cannot change this behavior.

So, either use a `class` type instead, or else don't use `ObjectToJsonString()` at all. There are plenty of alternative approaches available to get the output you want, such as by using `TJSONObject` and `TJSONArray` directly, or by using a 3rd party JSON library that supports `record` types as JSON objects.