# Spring4D Nullable<T> JSON serialization

Tags: json, delphi, serialization, spring4d

Is there a way to get `TJson.ObjectToJsonString()` properly serialize a `TNullableInteger` field in an object?

I tried to use an attribute on the field using a `JsonReflectAttribute` with a `TJSONInterceptor`, but then the integer value, if present, was serialized as string.

Comment: I think this isn't possible due to the design of Delphi JSON library. As you have learned, `TJSONInterceptor` only allows you to marshal data as string, array of strings, objects or array of objects. Since `TNullableInteger` from Spring4D is literally a record, it is marshaled as array of values of its fields (`FValue`, `FHasValue`). This is hard-coded (see [Write JSON with class and record types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72070414)) and there seems to be no standard way to hook into that behavior, because `TTypeMarshaller<TSerial>.MarshalValue` method is not virtual.

Answer (score 1):

JSON serialization that comes with Delphi is a disaster - as already mentioned in the comment to your question the design of `REST.Json` prevents any customization of record serializion from what I can see.

The only way known to me is to use a `TJsonSerializer` from `System.JSON.Serializers` and add a custom converter that can handle `Nullable<T>` quite easily:

```
uses
  Spring,
  System.JSON.Serializers,
  System.JSON.Readers,
  System.JSON.Writers,
  System.Rtti;

type
  TNullableConverter = class(TJsonConverter)
  public
    function CanConvert(ATypeInf: PTypeInfo): Boolean; override;
    function ReadJson(const AReader: TJsonReader; ATypeInf: PTypeInfo;
      const AExistingValue: TValue; const ASerializer: TJsonSerializer): TValue; override;
    procedure WriteJson(const AWriter: TJsonWriter; const AValue: TValue;
      const ASerializer: TJsonSerializer); override;
  end;

function TNullableConverter.CanConvert(ATypeInf: PTypeInfo): Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsNullable(ATypeInf);
end;

function TNullableConverter.ReadJson(const AReader: TJsonReader;
  ATypeInf: PTypeInfo; const AExistingValue: TValue;
  const ASerializer: TJsonSerializer): TValue;
begin
  Result := AExistingValue;
  Result.SetNullableValue(AReader.Value.Convert(GetUnderlyingType(ATypeInf), ISO8601FormatSettings));
end;

procedure TNullableConverter.WriteJson(const AWriter: TJsonWriter;
  const AValue: TValue; const ASerializer: TJsonSerializer);
var
  LTypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
  LValue: TValue;
begin
  LTypeInfo := GetUnderlyingType(AValue.TypeInfo);
  LValue := AValue.GetNullableValue;

  if LValue.IsEmpty then
    AWriter.WriteNull
  else
    if (LTypeInfo = TypeInfo(TDate)) or (LTypeInfo = TypeInfo(TTime)) then
      AWriter.WriteValue(LValue.Convert<string>(ISO8601FormatSettings))
    else
      AWriter.WriteValue(LValue);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Glienke!
I created a `TNullableSerializer` class that registers the `TNullableConverter` for the nullable field and used it to serialize the DTO. This works fine :-)

Comment: Further on I figured out that the new serializer does not handle correctly serialization of a `TDate` field (it produces a numeric value), so I ended up creating an extension method `ToJsonString()` for the DTO class that handles all fields as needed. However your suggestion is useful and we migth use it in the future, so thanks again!

Comment: I updated the code to also handle `Nullable<TDate>` and `Nullable<TTime>`. If you have `TDate` or `TTime` fields you can add yet another converter that handles those similarly.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Glienke, I updated the code following your update and now the `TDate` is serialized properly. I ran into another problem in `TJsonSerializer` - the field names were not converted to **Camel case**, so all the fields in the DTO had to be decorated with the `JsonName` attribute.

Comment: I could not find a variable named `ISO8601FormatSettings` in Spring4D, so I created a local one. Am I missing something?

Comment: Spring.pas in develop branch

Answer (score 0):

Could you write here your code of

```
TNullableSerializer
```

===
Thank you Mr.Nicko for the assistance.

I find Mr. Glienke's library very useful and use it in my projects but has lack of knowledge to do it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35810434)

Comment: @alexey-martynov - the code is below.

Comment: @Alexey You can also Suggest An Edit to an existing Answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
type
  TNullableSerializer = class(TJsonSerializer)
  strict private
    FNullableConverter: TJsonConverter;

  public
    constructor Create();
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  end;

constructor TNullableSerializer.Create();
begin
  inherited Create();
  Self.ContractResolver := TJsonDefaultContractResolver.Create(TJsonMemberSerialization.Public);

  Self.FNullableConverter := TNullableConverter.Create();
  Self.Converters.Add(Self.FNullableConverter);
end;

destructor TNullableSerializer.Destroy();
begin
  Self.FNullableConverter.Free();
  inherited Destroy();
end;

type
  TNullableConverter = class(TJsonConverter)
  strict private
    FJsonNullValueHandling: TJsonNullValueHandling;

  public
    constructor Create(AJsonNullValueHandling: TJsonNullValueHandling = TJsonNullValueHandling.Include);

    function CanConvert(ATypeInf: PTypeInfo): Boolean; override;
    function ReadJson(const AReader: TJsonReader; ATypeInf: PTypeInfo; const AExistingValue: TValue;
      const ASerializer: TJsonSerializer): TValue; override;
    procedure WriteJson(const AWriter: TJsonWriter; const AValue: TValue; const ASerializer: TJsonSerializer); override;
  end;

constructor TNullableConverter.Create(AJsonNullValueHandling: TJsonNullValueHandling);
begin
  inherited Create();
  Self.FJsonNullValueHandling := AJsonNullValueHandling;
end;

function TNullableConverter.CanConvert(ATypeInf: PTypeInfo): Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsNullable(ATypeInf);
end;

function TNullableConverter.ReadJson(const AReader: TJsonReader; ATypeInf: PTypeInfo; const AExistingValue: TValue;
  const ASerializer: TJsonSerializer): TValue;
begin
  Result := AExistingValue;
  Result.SetNullableValue(AReader.Value.Convert(GetUnderlyingType(ATypeInf), ISO8601FormatSettings));
end;


procedure TNullableConverter.WriteJson(const AWriter: TJsonWriter; const AValue: TValue; const ASerializer: TJsonSerializer);
begin
  var LTypeInfo := Spring.GetUnderlyingType(AValue.TypeInfo);
  var LValue := AValue.GetNullableValue();

  if (LValue.IsEmpty) then
  begin
    if (Self.FJsonNullValueHandling = TJsonNullValueHandling.Include) then
    begin
      AWriter.WriteNull();
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    if (LTypeInfo = TypeInfo(TDate)) or (LTypeInfo = TypeInfo(TTime)) then
    begin
      AWriter.WriteValue(LValue.Convert<string>(ISO8601FormatSettings));
    end
    else
    begin
      AWriter.WriteValue(LValue);
    end;
  end;
end;
```